# Limiting the memory consumption of tsvncache.exe in TortiseSVN?

Tags: svn, configuration, tortoisesvn, tsvncache

Does anyone know how to control the memory consumption of tsvncahce.exe used by TortiseSVN? It's consistently the largest consumer of memory on my machine. ~180mb on my Vista 64 machine. It uses more ram than VS2008, Sql Server and even my browser which usually has 4-5 tabs open.

this just doesnt seem normal. I have already started having it ignore drives and folders that it doesnt need to track, but this didnt really change things. Any advise from the gurus would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've already figured out how to configure tsvncache to ignore directories.  That is probably your best option.

You can also use that same settings dialog to set the status cache to *shell* or *none* instead of *default*. Either of those settings will disable tsvncache.exe completely, but the overlay icons will only appear for the currently visible folder, or not at all.  For more info, click the Help button on the dialog, that will take you to the Icon Overlay Settings section of the help file, which explains the settings in more detail.

Also, when you change the overlay icon settings, you either have to kill the tsvncache.exe process or logout for the settings to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

180 Mb? That's nothing! The thing leaks gigabytes on my dev machine, I have to kill it few times a week.

Do you have latest version installed. This problem is supposed to be fixed in 1.6.x (where x > 0 or 1, I saw a bug report).

If you set icon overlays to "shell" it will behave much better, but you lose recursive status icons...

Comment: I have the most recent version, 1.6.3.